# Comparing Dynamic SetConnectionString vs UseSqlServer in Middleware for Multi-Tenancy in .NET 8.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-8.0

I'm working on a multi-tenant application in .NET 8.0 and I am exploring ways to dynamically change the database connection string for each tenant. My current approach involves a custom middleware that sets the connection string for the `DbContext` on each request.

However, I'm uncertain about how this compares to using `UseSqlServer` and concerned about potential drawbacks, as I couldn't find detailed documentation on this specific use case.

Here is the middleware code:

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, ITenantLogic _tenantLogic, DbContext _db, IConfiguration _config)
{
    var tenantFromHost = await _tenantLogic.GetTenantByHostNameAsync(context.Request.Host.Host).ConfigureAwait(false);

    if (tenantFromHost == null)
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        var tenantConnStr = _config.GetConnectionString(tenantFromHost.DatabaseServer).Replace("[DBNAME]", tenantFromHost.DatabaseName);
        _db.Database.SetConnectionString(tenantConnStr);
    }
}
```

With this approach, the middleware determines the tenant based on the request's host name and sets the `DbContext`'s connection string accordingly.

I have several questions and concerns regarding this approach:

**Architectural fit:** is using middleware to set the connection string in line with best practices for software architecture, particularly regarding layer separation and responsibility?

**Comparison with `UseSqlServer`:** how does dynamically setting the connection string in middleware compare with configuring it through `UseSqlServer` in terms of best practices, performance, and potential issues?

**Entity Framework Core integration:** considering integration with Entity Framework Core in a .NET 8.0 application, are there specific concerns or best practices to be aware of with this middleware approach?

**Lack of documentation:** I've struggled to find comprehensive documentation or examples that discuss the implications of dynamically setting connection strings in middleware as opposed to using `UseSqlServer`. Can anyone provide insights or references that might help?

I am seeking guidance on whether this is a sound approach and if there are better alternatives or potential issues I should be aware of. Any advice, insights, or references to documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: This scenario is addressed [in the EF Core multi-tenancy docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/multitenancy#multiple-databases-and-connection-strings) and doesn't require such a middleware. Yes, there are problems, caused by the middleware order and the fact you're modifying the connection *after* the context was first created and possibly used. You can extract the entire connection selection logic into a separate services. The main point is that you never end up with a DbContext that points to the wrong database